# How to run `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless` command without parameters?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, aws-cli

Good evening. The question is about `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless` command. This command is used to deploy .Net apps to AWS Lambda service using AWS CloudFormation. When I try to run this command in Jenkins pipeline in stage:

```
stage('Update AWS lambda') {
            steps {
                bat "cd MyFinance.Api"
                bat "dotnet lambda deploy-serverless"
            }
        }
```

I receive errors about missing parameters:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\MyFinanceApiPipeline>dotnet
> lambda deploy-serverless  Amazon Lambda Tools for .NET Core
> applications (4.1.0) Project Home:
> https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli,
> https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet   Enter CloudFormation Stack
> Name: (CloudFormation stack name for an AWS Serverless application)
> Enter S3 Bucket: (S3 bucket to upload the build output) Enter
> CloudFormation Template: (Path to the CloudFormation template) Enter
> AWS Region: (The region to connect to AWS services, if not set region
> will be detected from the environment.) Can not determine AWS region.
> Either configure a default region or use the --region option.

But if I run this command via PowerShell in my project folder everything is ok. Near is a screenshot of command execution results.
[Successful command execution in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTGj8.png)
So, how to run this without parameters in Jenkins pipeline (like I made via PowerShell)?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks as though your Jenkins command is not finding your `serverless.template` file for some reason ... what happens if you specify it explicitly using `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless -pl [WorkingDirectory]\MyFinance.Api -t serverless.template`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you don't pass those requested parameters. You may pass these as arguments to the command

```
dotnet lambda deploy-serverless --stack-name replace-your-stack-name-here --s3-bucket replace-s3-bucket-name-here --region replace-with-region
```

You will have to navigate the folder where you have the "serverless.template" file before running this command. or optionally you can pass the path to the template file with the argument ***-t***

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying from Azure DevOps and getting this error,

```
1. Error: The process '/home/vsts/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-lambda' failed with exit code 255
2. "Missing" required parameter: --template
```

Make sure to navigate to the folder where you have the "serverless.template" file on **Path to Lambda Project** $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Buildfolder/ArtifactsFolder/severless.template_folder

[Same error on Azure Devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6yRr.png)